# Java: How to maintain a session of SSLSocket in pool to prevent a new handshake on each message

Tags: java, sockets, session, ssl, handshake

I am connecting a Java Server to a Android Application via SSLSocket. They communicate sending JSON objects.

My server needs to:

1. Check the login information of the app user
2. Keep up that connection for further communication to prevent another handshake (to reduce network data) and to identify the user on further interactions

I am done with the first point, the connection is established and works. But how can I achieve the second?

(Keeping the Thread the user connected to alive until he closes the socket seems to be inappropriate. I need to consider several thousand connections with connection time spans from one minute until maybe an hour.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSSE already does SSL session sharing. Don't worry about it. Just create SSLSockets as you need them. They will rejoin existing sessions if they can. Rejoining sessions uses an abbreviated handshake.

You don't need to make special arrangements at the server either. On the other hand, connection pooling at the client never hurts, but the server doesn't need to know much about it, except to loop accepting multiple requests from a connection rather than closing it after sending the first response.

Comment: I recorded the communication in wireshark and I can see something that looks like my certificate everytime I write something to the server. So it seems like it doesn't work for me.

I close the socket on the client side after getting an answer. Do I need to leave that opened?

And is there any way to identify the user via the session and identify whether he is logged in corretly?

Comment: Make sure the *server* has a reasonable SSL session timeout, say fifteen minutes.

Comment: Thanks, but could you be a little bit more specific? On which object do I need to do that? SSLServerSocket? And how can I do that? setSoTimeout() sets the blocking timeout, when waiting for a connection. I found no method to set the session timeout.

Comment: SSLSocket.getSession().getSessionContext().setSessionTimeout().

Comment: So this seems to work, thanks! Relating to my other question asked above: I have a method like login(username, pwHash). The user needs to login to access the server. Is there any way to mark a session as logged in and store the username within this session? So I won't need to check the login data on each request but only once per session?

Comment: No there isn't, but you can do the converse: get the SSLSession ID from the SSLSession when login succeeds and store that somewhere in a table of logged-in sessions, then check later to see if the current SSL session has a logged-in session ID.